# Is it possible to consume a key event from emscripten?

Tags: c, event-handling, sdl-2, emscripten

I'm building a small SDL 2 program and compiling to web assembly with Emscripten. All is well so far, but control and W are bother mapped within my program to specific functions, and I'm noticing (after the fact) that emscripten's use of them does nothing to prevent CTRL+W from closing the window outright.

I can probably remap my keys, but I'm curious whether anyone is aware of a way to consume the event so that it doesn't reach the browser. If that is possible, even in a limited way, it would be ideal.